# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'uri.split')]on React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I got a problem when upload image on react native
[image: Alert]

and here is my code

```
_pickImage = async () => {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    const { cancelled, uri } = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 4],
      base64: true
    });
    if (!cancelled) this.setState({ ImageKTP: uri });
    this.createFormData();
  };
```

and here is createFormData

```
 createFormData = async (uri) =>  {
        const {ImageKTP} = this.state;
        let imageUri = uri.split('.');
        let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('ImageKTP', {
          imageUri,
          name: `ImageKTP.${fileType}`,
          type: `image/${fileType}`,
        });
          fetch('http://192.168.0.20/profile.php?ImageKTP=' + ImageKTP,{
            method: 'POST',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
               body: formData
            })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) =>{
              alert(responseJson);
          })
          .catch((error)=>{
              console.error(error);
          });
          
    
      };
```

Any Solution for this? I still dont get it how to get the uri
Thank you

Comment: you are taking uri from the function parameter so pass the uri in the funtion call this.setState({ ImageKTP: uri }, () => {
        this.createFormData(uri);
      });

Comment: ok thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `createFromData` only when you successfully have `uri` set

```
if (!cancelled) {
      this.setState({ ImageKTP: uri }, () => {
        this.createFormData();
      });
    }
```

- ```
   createFormData = async uri => {
       const { ImageKTP } = this.state;
       if (!ImageKTP) return;

       /** Your processing code... */
     };
  ```

Comment: still same issue [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'uri.split')]

Comment: @JovitaSutanto Have you updated your createFormData like in the answer ?

Comment: wait a minute i check it first